# D3.js Disappearing bubbles in bubble chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, circle-pack

I am trying to display a D3 bubble chart for an array which can contain some 0 values. If the number of 0s gets to high bubbles start to "disappear". See this example (it should show 10 bubbles):
[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WWxqh/1/)

Am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <meta name="language" content="de">
   <title>Disappearing bubble Problem</title>

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var r = 700
var bubble_layout = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([r,r])
    .padding(1.5);

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width" , r)
    .attr("height", r)

var arr = [
   { name : '1', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '2', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '3', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '4', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '5', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '6', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '7', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '8', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '9', value: 1 }
  ,{ name : '10', value: 1 } 
  ,{ name : '11', value: 0 } //Adding data elements with value 0 makes bubbles disappear
  ,{ name : '12', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '13', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '14', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '15', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '16', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '17', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '18', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '19', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '20', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '21', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '22', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '23', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '24', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '25', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '26', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '27', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '28', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '29', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '30', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '31', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '32', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '33', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '34', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '35', value: 0 }
  ,{ name : '36', value: 0 }  
];

var selection = vis.selectAll("g.node")
              .data(bubble_layout.nodes({children: arr}).filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }) ); 

//Enter
node = selection.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return 'aaaaaa'; });

node.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".3em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

} );
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <span id='chart'>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your circles don't disappear, they are rendered but are covered by others.

You can change the sort order of the pack layout to something other than ascending - which is the default. It can be set to null

```
var bubble_layout = d3.layout.pack()
                      .sort(null) // <-- HERE
                      .size([r,r])
                      .padding(1.5);
```

Also, you might want to filter your selection to include only items with a value greater than 0, to avoid creating circles with zero radius.

```
var node = selection.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                        return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; 
                    })
                    .filter(function(d){    
                        return d.value > 0; // <-- HERE 
                    })
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/WWxqh/4/

To prevent the uniform look you need to change the `value` property, since d3.js uses it to do its magic. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/WWxqh/5/